# MySQL/MariaDB Read only except for a single table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, read-only-database

I Have a database with lots of tables and read_only enabled in the config, is it possible to set a single table to be writable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can do `read_only = 1 (except for table x);`

So I would think your best option would be to set all your users to read_only:

`GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'user'@'1.2.3.4';`

Then the users that need to write to that table would be given permission to write to just that table. e.g.

`GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON 'dbname.tablename'@'1.2.3.4';`